# Realization of an external bottom bar

Tags: android, uinavigationbar, navigation-drawer

currently I'm trying to realize a bottom bar different from standard.(like in the attached picture)
[Bottom bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8JQa.png)
I want to realize this for an Android App.

I have all with gradient etc. [[Icon with gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt7QS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZAQL.png)[Icon without gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngHn9.png)
As well the backgorund round cornered with gradient [Round cornered box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKAKx.png)

I cannot add this pictures to a normal bottom bar which I have already, then the color get lost or the app crash.

I tried adding the images in a existing bottom bar but these is mainly based on colors and the gradient also cause trouble there. The conversion of images with the built in android tool didn't work for these gradient icons as well.

My question is:
Can the function be realized in a button with multiple sections or something like that?
Are only XML files suitable to build this and not .png sources?

I read that this menu I chose maybe isn't suitable and a layout could be more suitable.
Looks like this now:
[Current state navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX1ce.png)

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home2"
        android:icon="@drawable/exert_menu_bottom_icon_footprints_gradient"
        android:title="" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/steps"
        android:icon="@drawable/exert_menu_bottom_icon_boost_gradient"
        android:title=""
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/transactions"
        android:icon="@drawable/exert_menu_bottom_icon_wallet_gradient"
        android:title=""
  />
</menu>
```

```html
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="200dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/exert_menu_bottom_border_gradient"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use chatGPT to create the bottombar I introduced before:

To create the gradient color I use this file, unfortunately android cannot recognize this file I saved in res/color
There is no preview of the gradient color available.Please let me know if I have to change my structure. The app crashes as soon I open the page with the used color. **Binary XML file line #60 in com.sp.vigour:layout/activity_nav_drawer: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView**

```
   " color_test.xml"                  
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <gradient xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:startColor="#ED7A21"
    android:endColor="#7BC032"
    android:angle="145"
    android:startX="0.3"
    android:endX="0.7"
    android:startY="0.3"
    android:endY="0.7"
    android:type="linear" />
```

This one is called by gradient_color.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/color_test" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:color="@color/farbgradient_end"/>
  </selector>
```

And this one is called by my bottom navigation:

com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

```
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/exert_menu_bottom_border_gradient"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"
        android:scrollY="-6dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/gradient_color"
        />
```